# Eloquent can I refer to model relationship in where?

Tags: php, orm, laravel, eloquent

I have models with appropriate belongsTo/hasMany relationships defined, and I want to query one table based on properties of a joined table. I can do it if I define the join in my query, but is there something I can do so that I don't have to define the join everytime I want to query a model on it's relation?

Forinstance. the following does not work, unless I define a join:

```
FileAssociation::with('file')->where('files.file_type_version_id', $file->file_type_version_id)->get()
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is Eager Load Constraints basically you can do this

```
FileAssociation::with(array('file' => function($query)
{
  $query->where('file_type_version_id',$file->file_type_version_id);
}))->get();
```

Check out the docs on [Eager Loading](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading)

**Edit**

If you are using Laravel 4.1 now you have access to the `whereHas()` method if you want to return the `FileAssociation` only if there is at least one "file"

```
FileAssociation::whereHas('file' => function($query)
{
  $query->where('file_type_version_id',$file->file_type_version_id);
})->get();
```

Check out the docs on [Quering Relations](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#querying-relations)

Comment: This will still unfortunately load all the FileAssociations regardless of a null result set from the eager load. You can parse eloquent collections with it's filter method afterwards; although it can be an expensive operation. +1 for the eager load constraint.

Comment: @DavidBarker If he is using Laravel 4.1 I think he can use `FileAssociation::whereHas('file')` I think with this you make sure there is at least one "file".

Comment: well that'll be awesome... I've not had a chance to look at the changes to 4.1 yet, thanks for the heads up!

Comment: Hmm.. I may not have explained myself clear enough. I don't want to only get the file if the type_version_id is equal, I want to only get a *result* if the file's type_version_id is equal.

Comment: @Damon Well the first query should return that? What do you get when you run the first query? Basically the first query should load `FileAssociation` with all `"File"` that meet the where condition (constraining the models relation). If you want you could apply further conditions to the `FileAssociation` before getting the results at the end (e.g ->where('something',$something)->get();

Comment: @Damon and with `whereHas()` you get results only if there is at least one result in the model relation that satisfies the condition, in this case `->where('file_type_version_id',$file->file_type_version_id)`.

Comment: when I ran the first query I seemed to get all the FileAssociations but only the File's that met the condition. I just want the FileAssocations whose File's meet the condition

Comment: mind you i'm getting the data I need using a ->join() it just seems weird to ahve to define the join when the model knows it already